# how to group ldap search results by attributes and not by cn. using bash

Tags: bash, ldap

I have this scriplet that pulls data from a ldap. it lists the attributes with the cn and the value. but it goes through all the attributes of a cn and then moves to the next.

```
for node  in "${HOSTS[@]}"; do
        LDAP_URI="ldaps://${node}:${LDAP_PORT}"
        while IFS=: read -r key val; do
        [[ $key = cn ]] && { cn=${val# }; continue; }
        if [[ $val =~ ^\ -?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?$ ]]; then
            attr=$(sed 's/-/_/g' <<< "$key")l"
            printf '%s, cn="%s %s\n"' "$attr" "$cn" "$val"
        fi
        done < <( ${LDAPSEARCH} -LLL -H "${LDAP_URI}" -x -D "${BINDDN}" -w "${LDAP_PASSWD}" -b "cn=monitor")
    done;
```

the code above produces output like this:

```
"connections, cn="1636  -632
"bytessent, cn="1636  492842558
"connections, cn="1389  698
"bytessent, cn="1389  389256181
```

but I do not want to group by cn but group by attribute like this:

```
"bytessent, cn="1389  389261940
"bytessent, cn="1636  711130488
"connections, cn="1389  700
"connections, cn="1636  -632
```

what would be the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One idea would be to pipe the entire output to `sort`.

I don't have all the bits-n-pieces to get OP's working so I'll simulate with an `echo`:

```
echo '"connections, cn="1636  -632
"bytessent, cn="1636  492842558
"connections, cn="1389  698
"bytessent, cn="1389  389256181' | sort
```

This generates:

```
"bytessent, cn="1389  389256181
"bytessent, cn="1636  492842558
"connections, cn="1389  698
"connections, cn="1636  -632
```

Adding to OP's code (see last line):

```
for node  in "${HOSTS[@]}"; do
    ... snip ...
done | sort                            # send all output to sort
```

---

I'm guessing OP really wants to end each line with a `"` so that it looks like:

```
"bytessent, cn="1389  389256181"
"bytessent, cn="1636  492842558"
"connections, cn="1389  698"
"connections, cn="1636  -632"
```

To accomplish this just need to tweak the `printf` format to switch the last `"` and the `\n`:

```
printf '%s, cn="%s %s\n"' "$attr" "$cn" "$val"         # before
printf '%s, cn="%s %s"\n' "$attr" "$cn" "$val"         # after
```

Comment: this works great. 
If i may how can i capture the attribute so that i can add a header before each attribute session? per instance add `#BYTESSENT` before the bytessent attribute session of the output. I hope i make myself clear!

Comment: sorry, not sure I'm following you; I'd suggest ... accept this answer (if it works for the given question) and create a new question with the new requirement